# Data Factory - pass multiple variables to foreach activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm creating a pipeline on ADF and basically I've 2 variables and 1 object.

The variables are arrays:

1. CountryPartition: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k1hm.png
2. YearPartition: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4B2o.png

And I've a lookup activity that I'm querying a azure storage table to get more parameters: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Csv.png

I want to append dynamically the CountryPartition, YearPartition and databricksPath and pass to foreach activity. For that example and following the parameters it will run 16 times. 2 different databricks paths for 4 countries and 2 years: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqlLs.png

I tried to create this solution `@union(activity('Config Table Synapse Fact Query').output.value, array(concat('{"countryPartition" :',variables('CountryPartition'),'}')), array(concat('{"yearPartition" :',variables('YearsPartition'),'}')))`

and I obtained this result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypytv.png

but when I tried to pass this result to Foreach activity it got a error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1PIn.png

Foreach activity: https://i.stack.imgur.com/exRka.png

*Details
The expression 'item().countryPartition' cannot be evaluated because property 'countryPartition' doesn't exist, available properties are 'PartitionKey, RowKey, Timestamp, ID, databricksPath, databricksTable, onOff, synapseTable, tableType'.*

It seems that it only considers the values ​​in the first json and not the other variables (countryPartition and yearPartition)

Can anyone please help me in achieving this

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because, you applied `@union` and combined strings to an array of objects (**concat('{"countryPartition" :',variables('CountryPartition'),'}')** is a string).

- To overcome the error you can use the following (convert the above string to json):

```
@union(activity('Config Table Synapse Fact Query').output.value, array(json(concat('{"countryPartition" :',variables('CountryPartition'),'}'))), array(json(concat('{"yearPartition" :',variables('YearsPartition'),'}'))))
```

- **But this does not help to get the 16 combinations of databricks path**, country partition and year partition. You would have to use multiple loops to get all the required combinations (as in image 4).
- Instead, you can utilize dataflows to get the required result. You can follow the procedure given below.
- We already have 2 array variables for `countryPartition and yearPartition` (I took these as array parameters for demo). Now I used a `for each` activity along with `append variable` activity (which is inside for each.) to get an array of databricks paths.

[image]

- Now, I need to pass `paths, countryPartition, yearPartition` arrays to dataflow, where I obtain the combination of each (16 combinations as in image 4).

[image]

- Inside my dataflow, I have taken a sample source file with just one row (this file is used only to achieve what we want. Data in this file does not affect the process).
- Create 3 sources with this sample file. Apply `derived column` transformation on each of the source. For source 1, I added country column with value as `unfold($country)`. Similarly for source 2 (path column with value as`unfold($path)` ) and source 3 (year column with value as`unfold($year)`).

[image]

- Use select on each of the above only to select the required column (country, path and year respectively).

[image]

- Now we have 3 tables each containing one required column. You can apply `join` transformation (custom cross join with condition as `true()`). Use cross join on tables containing country and path. Then apply cross join on the result of above and year table.

[image]

- Select sink as your storage account (in `writeToCSV`). The required result will be written to your sink as a csv file. The following is the debug output:
  [image]
- The following is an image of resultant CSV file with required records:

[image]

Now you can use lookup to read this `req_rows.csv` file. You can pass `@activity('Lookup req csv').output.value` as items in for each. Inside this you can pass the path, yearPartition and countryPartition values as `@item().path` , `@item().country`, `@item().year` from your databricks notebook activity.

Comment: thanks a lot Saideep, you saved my day ! the only modification I made was in relation to the sink. I put it to be cached so I don't need to save any csv and put one more activity for the foreach, so I pass the dataflow output to the foreach like this @array(activity('Data flow1').output.runStatus.output.sink1.value). Once again thanks a lot !!